# How do I get a class to return a value?

Tags: javascript, class

how does the built in date class work in javascript?

for instance:

```
var timestamp = new Date('02/14/1994')
// returns milliseconds without having to call timestamp.miliseconds
// it just passes it into the variable
```

Comment: Your premise is wrong, `timestamp` is an instance of `Date`, it is not the number of milliseconds.

Comment: What information are you trying to obtain exactly? Is there a particular format or output that you're looking for?

Comment: When used in a numeric context though, the date object is implicitly coerced into a number. `+timestamp` gives 
`761209200000`.

Comment: yes exactly, its my understanding that classes are just templates of objects so theoretically if I log timestamp  it should give me {property1: 'blah', property2:' blah'} , INSTEAD it gives me 761209200000, how do I make my classes return a value rather than an object

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is not exactly clear on this I suspect you came across something 2 special methods with JavaScript classes that are automatically being called when an object is converted to a string or is compared with another value:

- [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)
- [valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)

Given the following class we can play around with these:

```js
class Test {
  toString() {
    return 'Hello world';
  }
  
  valueOf() {
    return 3;
  }
}

const t = new Test();
console.log( t );
console.log( t.toString() );
console.log( `${ t }` );
console.log( t > 2 );
```

The `Date` object is very similar here. When you call `(new Date()).toString()` you will get the full date printed out. If you do cast it into a number with `+(new Date())` the internal `valueOf()` is being used to convert it into its numeric value.

Comment: `console.log()` does not implicitly call `toString()` on arguments. Your first output might be better exemplified with ``console.log(`${t}`)``

Comment: Right, because it also might be printed out as an object. Changed it